# Prove that if $G$ is abelian, then $H = \{a \in G \mid a^2 = e\}$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Prove that $H = \{a \in G \mid a^2 = e\}$ is subgroup of $G$, where 
>   $e$ is the neutral element of $G$.

I need some help to approach this question.

Comment: What is the definition of a subgroup?  What have you previously done to prove something is a subgroup?

Comment: Sub group is a sub set in G with meets the group axioms

Comment: @user1798362: Can you state those axioms? Which ones do you not know how to prove that this $H$ satisfies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** To show it is a subgroup you must show the following three things:

$1)$ $e \in H$.

$2)$ If $a$ and $b$ are in $H$ then so is $ab$.

$3)$ If $a$ is in $H$, then so is $a^{-1}$.

To show these three things, think about what it means for a particular element to be in $H$ and try and use this to show that the elements you want to be in $H$ actually are.

Once you have shown this is true, you might like to think about why we needed the group to be abelian, and see if you can find a (non-abelian) group where $H$ is not a subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** To show it is a subgroup, you need to answer yes to the following questions, and justify your answers.

Questions to answer:

$(1)$ What is $e^2\,$? So is $\,e \in H\,$?

- (**This will prove the identity of $G$ is in $H$**.)

$(2)$ If $\,a, b \in H$, then $a^2 = b^2 = e.\;$ So we need to know whether $(ab) \in H$?:
$Yes, ab \in H$ if you can show that $(ab)^2 = e$.
*Tip: use the fact that $G$ is **abelian, and so $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$***

- (If $ab\in H$, this would prove that $H$ is **closed under the group operation** of $G$).

$(3)$ If $a \in H$, is $a^{-1} \in H$?

- (If so, this would prove that $H$ is **closed under taking inverses**.)

Comment: Very nice hint and guidance! +1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find a homomorphism from $G$ whose kernel is exactly $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Prove that if $\,G\,$ is an abelian group then $\,G^n:=\{ g^n\;;\;g\in G\}\,$ is a subgroup of G .

Further hint: $\,(xy)^n=x^ny^n\,$ ...what about inverses?

Answer (score 0):

*Closure*

If $a,b \in H $ then $abab=abba=ab^2a=aea=a^2=e \in H$

*Associativity*

If $a,b,c \in H$ then $(ab)c=a(bc)$ because $G$ is a group

*Identity*

$e\in H$ because $ee=e^2=e$

*Inverse*

Let $a \in H$ Then  $a^2=e=aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a$ Multiply by $a$ then $a^{-1}aa=aa^{-1}a \rightarrow a^{-1}e=ea \rightarrow a^{-1}=a \in H$. The object $a^{-1}\in G$ exists because $G$ is a group